# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, active-directory

I'm getting an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll

randomly while moving a handful of users.

It is strange, there seems to be no rhyme or reason as to when they occur, I have it in a TRY and for some reason recently it started crashing the app. In the debugger, they pop-up, you are able to continue over them and finish the thread, the "failure" actions work, and re-run the move on the next cycle.

<--Code Snip it-->

```
If Action_Exe = "Update" Then
    If IsDBNull(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16)) Then
        Trace.WriteLine("Error in datatable. NULL found.")
        Trace.WriteLine("Record: " & Master_Loop)
        Trace.WriteLine("User: " & Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(1))
        Trace.WriteLine("AD Current Path: " & newUser.Path)
        'Update to try again
        CycleSQLQUERY.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbo].[AMS_Processing_Table] SET [Process_FLAG] = 3 WHERE [TrackingID] = '" & Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(0).ToString & "';"
        WinEventLog.WriteEntry("Account Processing Thread: Null Var Found in Datatable. - " & Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(1) & "-" & Master_Loop, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit, 1614)
        Continue For
    End If
    Trace.WriteLine("OLD: " & Replace(newUser.Path, newUser.Name & ",", ""))
    Trace.WriteLine("New: " & LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/"))
    If LCase(Replace(newUser.Path, newUser.Name & ",", "")) <> LCase(LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/")) Then
        Thread.Sleep(100)
        Dim UserObjPath As String = newUser.Path
        Dim SuccessfulMove As Boolean = True
        Try
            newUser.MoveTo(New DirectoryEntry(LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/")))
        Catch CatchALL As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine(CatchALL.GetType)
            Trace.WriteLine("OLD: " & Replace(newUser.Path, newUser.Name & ",", ""))
            Trace.WriteLine("New: " & LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/"))
            WinEventLog.WriteEntry("Account Processing Thread: Failed to move user object in AD. - " & Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(1) & " - " & CatchALL.Message & "; OLD: " & LCase(Replace(newUser.Path, newUser.Name & ",", "")) & "; NEW:" & LCase(LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/")), EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit, 1611)
            SuccessfulMove = False
            CycleSQLQUERY.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbo].[AMS_Processing_Table] SET [Process_FLAG] = 3 WHERE [TrackingID] = '" & Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(0).ToString & "';"
            Try
                CycleSQLQUERY.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex_SQL As Exception
                'addin 5/3/16
            End Try
            Continue For
        End Try
        If SuccessfulMove = True Then

        Dim ChangeLineCount As Int64
```

Any though, suggestions, tips, or fixes would be greatly appreciated.
This is a multi-thread application, in particular this part. I have tried to dial down the number of threads and same issue.

Comment: It seems you can't bold code. The location I am getting the error is on **newUser.MoveTo(New DirectoryEntry(LDAPSpecial & Replace(Processing_DataResults.Rows.Item(Master_Loop)(16), "/", "\/")))**

Comment: A code block is a code block for a reason. :)

Comment: No one? :-/
well, I guess I am glad that I am not the only one that has found it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have found what my issue was, incase anyone else runs into this.
What was happening was earlier in the code I am connecting to AD (with just the domain name) later in the code if the operation was a move it would run the code above, creating a new connection to AD. when connecting to active directory, it will choose an available domain controller (desired action) this is helpful if a DC goes down, or the load is too large to handle the extra load.
Anyways the second connection would sometimes connect to another DC. it would error out when both connections were not on the same DC, most likely because the changes had not replicated to that dc yet, given they had just taken place less than a second ago.
So, my fix for the problem is I am loading which dc the first connection is using by pulling dnshostname from LDAP, and using that in the second connection.